# Visual keyframe in Blender 4.1

Tags: animation, keyframes

In earlier Blender versions, if you pressed I to insert a keyframe, you could choose between various keyframe types, especially you could choose visual keyframe.

Unfortunately i cannot find this option in Blender 4.1.

I know i can create my own keyset for visual keyframe (which takes some time to make), but i would prefer to have that already as it was before.

Is there a way to have it like before in older versions?

Comment: You know very well questions about Alpha versions are usually off-topic here ;) Why don't you just file a bug report and say, it's not working anymore? Maybe the developers will reconsider bringing it back in like it was. Or tell you how it works now. Because since it's not like it was before, I guess there is not simply a way to "have it like before", only workarounds which you mention yourself.

Comment: Yep, but add-on questions are also off-topic, but animation nodes questions will always be answered here and there are tons of AN questions here. And this is true for other add-ons as well like Sverchok etc. And also if it is about GN, there are tons of alpha questions about that...so...i just hope it won't be closed - but i expect it will be - but hopefully someone nice answers before that ;)

Comment: and tbh i have no idea whether it is a bug - the developers changed a lot and i thought they might think it is easier to just press i and have them inserted automatically instead of click another time in the menu what keys should be inserted

Comment: This has changed and some settings can be found in user prefs/animation, but this is still undocumented in 4.1 documentation

Comment: @lemon: thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a short research. The shortcut <kbd>I</kbd> seems to be automatically inserting a keyframe for all transform channels now. The new shortcut for the keyframe menu is now <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: k does nothing in my version....i have to check my shortcuts - i can see the command - but it does nothing

Comment: @Chris I downloaded 4.1 just now, and I found it out with Google in 30 seconds ;) There is a Youtube video that's just 5 hours old where this is explained. Seems to be a really fresh change.

Comment: did u try in 4.1 alpha?

Comment: It seems default keyframe are with I and no menu, based on the user preferences, except if a keying set is active. (and k works for me too)

Comment: @Chris Sure in Alpha, not in a separate branch... I usually found branches having certain features exclusively that they are testing, but therefore others missing that are already in alpha and beta versions, so I stick to them.

Comment: after downloading a new version from today, it worked....strange

Comment: I think many people will add a lot of unwanted keyframes with this new behavior : ))

Comment: @lemon Certainly :D The video I found says something about user preferences, didn't pay much attention to it. On my Blender the `K` worked by default, so... Chris: yeah, it must be really new.

Comment: some more information here, https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.1/animation_rigging/#keying